# In VS Code, how do you add/remove a jar file to Project and External Dependencies?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I need to remove a jar file from my project and add another one.

If I open my projects in the JAVA PROJECTS view, I can see a 'Project and External Dependencies' folder and it has the jar file I wish to remove...

[image]

However, I can't find a plus or minus icon or anything like that to indicate I can remove one jar file or add another.

And I've tried sticking the new jar file in my project's lib directory; it won't recognize the new jar file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: is that dependency specified in your gradle files? If so, just edit your grade files to remove the dependency. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Thanks.  So this may be a stupid question - but I'm not totally sure what these gradle files are.  I have a build.gradle file in my root directory but it doesn't contain any references to the jar file I'm trying to remove.

I even did a global search for that jar file and several others listed in Project and External Dependencies and could not find them listed anywhere.  Thanks.

Comment: Hold on - I think maybe I've found something...

Comment: Okay I think this might work...  I removed the old jar files from a file called build.gradle in my top-most directory and replaced with the new jar files.  I think it's going to work now - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it just by editing your gradle configuration file (Ex. `build.gradle`) to remove / add dependencies as you wish. The dependencies are declared there. Docs: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html.